# PHP issues with namespaces and singletons

Tags: php, namespaces, singleton

Hey guys I'm having an issue that I think is because due to namespaces, I have my parent class `TheParent` where I do some stuff, add it to `$this` then extend to a child class expecting that `$this` will carry over, but everything inside except what is explicitly mentioned in the parents constructor seems to vanish (the `$timeout = 10`) I'm trying to figure out where I borked this code at, and if anyone could explain it to me why this is not working like I would think it should?

```
 Namespace Services;

 Class TheParent
 {
    public function __construct($timeout = 10, array $options = array())
    {
        $this->setAuth($options)->setTimeout($timeout);
    }

    // other methods that put information into $this

    public function useRest()
    {
        require_once 'RestAggregator.php'

        $this->message = REST::getInstance();

        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        print_r($this); die;

    }
 }


 Namespace Services;

 Class REST Extends TheParent
 {
    private static  $instance   = NULL;
    private         $messages   = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->messages = self::getDataMessages();
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(! isset(REST::$instance))
        {
            REST::$instance = New REST();
        }

        return REST::$instance;
    }

    protected function getDataMessages()
    {
        return REST::$instance->messages = array(
          'foo'   => '4',
          'bar'   => '5',
          'baz'   => '6',
        );
    }
 }
```

This is the rest object returned, you would THINK that I would also have data from `TheParent` which is where things like `_appKey` etcetera have already been defined before being passed to `REST`

```
Services\REST Object
(
    [type] => 
    [messages:Services\REST:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [groups:Services\REST:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [_following:protected] => 
    [_sent:protected] => 
    [_private:protected] => 
    [_received:protected] => 
    [_appKey:protected] => 
    [_appSecret:protected] => 
    [_authToken:protected] => 
    [_authSecret:protected] => 
    [_authCode:protected] => 
    [_redirectUri:protected] => 
    [_smAuth:protected] => 
    [_accessToken:protected] => 
    [_tigerToken:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => 
    [_timeout:protected] => 10
    [_cookieJar:protected] => 
    [dbh] => 
    [opts] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: Looks like `TheParent` is in the `Services` namespace, not `Services\REST`.

Comment: I corrected that just now, the response that I have is posted below the code. Plus 1 for catching that before I did though =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying that class REST extends (is a child of) class Parent. But in class Parent you are referring to methods in the child class. Child classes can use parent methods but parent classes have no access to their child classes. Extending a class is a one way street.

Comment: i see you added a new REST object. You should name that different than the REST class or you are asking for trouble.

Comment: that rest object is created with getInstance(), its an instance of the rest class

Comment: what is the purpose of the Parent class. Just use one Rest class.

Comment: thanks you helped me figure out what I was doing wrong. Accepted and plus one.

Comment: glad i could help. wasn't sure i was.